# Qt5 mainwindow is hidden always return true

Tags: qt, qt5, qmainwindow

I want to know if the window is hidden or not so I can restore it from SystemTray.

I crated a very simple application to test, however even the window is shown, it return `true`.
mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "From mainwindow" << this->isHidden();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    qDebug() << "From main" << w.isHidden();
    return a.exec();
}
```

And the output is like this:

```
From mainwindow true
From main false
```

In my real program, I have a `systemtrayIcon`. I use these two methods to call isHidden function.
Method1

```
MainWindow *mainwindow = new MainWindow();
qDebug() << "pointer" << mainwindow->isHidden();
```

Method2

```
MainWindow mainwindow;
qDebug() << "not pointer" << mainwindow.isHidden();
```

And the result is like this:

```
pointer true
not pointer true
```

The truth is my program window is shown instead of hidden. How to get the correct status of mainwindow?

Comment: The problem might be that it's too early to ask whether a window is visible from it's constructor. It's still hidden while it's constructing.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this?